# Many-to-many relationship between same table with extra column in EF

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

LOL. This is perhaps the most complicated case for EF to do the modeling? I even doubt if this scenario is supported.
My business is like I need to know which Application matches another Application for what reason. So the table representing the relationship looks like this:

PrimaryApplicationID, SecondaryApplicationID, MatchedRuleID

OK. Now is it even possible I can use EF to represent this relationship? If yes, what special thing I need to do in database side? I'm using database-first approach, but this doesn't quite matter, does it?

Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Database-First you would create three tables, for example:

- Table `Applications`

  ```
  ApplicationId           int  NOT NULL PK
  ...Other columns...
  ```
- Table `Rules`

  ```
  RuleId                  int  NOT NULL PK
  ...Other columns...
  ```
- Table `MatchingApplications`

  ```
  PrimaryApplicationId    int  NOT NULL PK, FK to Applications table
  SecondaryApplicationId  int  NOT NULL PK, FK to Applications table
  MatchedRuleId           int  NOT NULL FK to Rules table
  ```

The double-PK in `MatchingApplications` is meant to be a composite key. The double-FK is meant as *two* separate foreign key relationships to the same table `Applications.` You cannot enable cascading delete for both relationships because SQL Server won't allow more than one cascading delete path between the same tables.

EF should create three entities from this database schema:

- `Application` entity with two collections with element type `MatchingApplication`
- `Rule` entity with one collection with element type `MatchingApplication`
- `MatchingApplication` entity with two navigation references of type `Application` and one navigation reference of type `Rule`.